# Inputtting note names into csound

Tags: software

In most of the `csound` examples the pitches are input using frequencies in Hertz, or their numerical `octave.pitch_class` notation.

Is there a way to input them in a manner that uses the note-names, 'a','b' etc. in a sensible manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no experience with CSound what-so-ever, and it seems to me not the type of environment that actually *wants* their users to use real note names.

I did however find something that might prove useful to you: [the 'no' filter](http://mikelkuehn.com/ngen/man2/html/input.htm#no), which translates note names to an internal representation of that node (as a real number). I hope that might prove useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do this. Either use a string and then " decode" it inside your instrument or use a score pre-processor like:
http://www.csounds.com/manual/html/CsBeats.html
To convert the more names and rhythm to a standard score. You can write the score pre processor yourself if you prefer, in any scripting language.